# How to define /health endpoint without version of base url using goswagger in golang

Tags: go, swagger, webapi, health-check, go-swagger

I've generated swagger using goswagger in golang application. My base url is
`[ Base URL: /{service-name}/api/v1 ]`
and health endpoint after click on try out option in swagger
`/{service-name}/api/v1/health` but in actual it should be without version `/{service-name}/api/health`.

I've defined configuartion in main.go

//     Schemes: https  
//     Host:  
//     BasePath: /command-provisioning-service/api/v1  
// swagger:meta  
package main  
...  
...  
...

and in health.go  
// Schemes: https  
// Host:  
// BasePath: /command-provisioning-service/api/  
// swagger:route GET /health Health  
// Return the health status  
func registerHealthRoute(router *mux.Router) {
...  
...  
...  
}